# Merge laravel 4 multiple relashionships

Tags: php, laravel

I have two relashionships in laravel v4.2. When I merge these two relashion into third function and then I call third function then I receive Uncought exception. Below is my code

```
   public function following_friend() {
         return $this->hasOne('Friend', 'following_id', 'id');
   }

   public function follower_friend() {
        return $this->hasOne('Friend', 'follower_id', 'id');
   }

   public function mutual_friends() {
        return $this->following_friend->merge($this->follower_friend);
   }

    public static function get_users_infomation_by_ids($login_id, $users_arr = array()) {
        $users = User::where(function($sql) use($login_id, $users_arr) {
                    $sql->whereIn('id', $users_arr);
                })                
                ->with('mutual_friends')
                ->get(array('id', 'username', 'full_name', 'is_live', 'message_privacy', 'picture'));
        return (!empty($users) && count($users) > 0) ? $users->toArray() : array();
    }
```

I don't know that where is the problem in merging these two relashionships.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write like below :-

```
public static function get_users_infomation_by_ids($login_id, $users_arr = array()) {
        $users = User::with('mutual_friends')
                ->where(function($sql) use($login_id, $users_arr) {
                    $sql->whereIn('id', $users_arr);
                })
                ->get(array('id', 'username', 'full_name', 'is_live', 'message_privacy', 'picture'));
        return (!empty($users) && count($users) > 0) ? $users->toArray() : array();
    }
```

Since I have used like this for one of my Project :-

```
public function getShipmentDetails($shipmentId = null) {
        $response = Shipment::with('pdDetails','shipmentDocuments')
                ->where('id', $shipmentId)
                ->first();
        if($response) {
            return $response->toArray();
        }
    }
```

It works for me.

Comment: still facing below exception
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer::display() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given